# Yocto: Can't install recipe into a non-standard directory

Tags: directory, path, yocto, bitbake

**The task:**

Our system has a readonly rootfs so I need to modify the NetworkManager directories to links that point to a readwrite directory, otherwise it doesn't work right.

**The problem:**

The chosen installation directory for some files is not present on the image.

Using "/data" as the install directory, which is mounted using fstab from another partition:

```
/dev/root            /                    auto       ro                    1  0
/dev/emmcp2          /data                ext4       defaults              0  0
```

and is added to base-files package:

```
do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}/data
}

FILES_${PN} += "/data"
```

During the build process, "/data/NetworkManager" and the other subdirectories bellow appear in the pre-packaged directory (so install command seems to work fine).

After build finishes, it is missing "do_populate_sysroot" step BUT it does have the "/data" directory in "build/tmp/sysroots-components/"

If I use "/home/root" as the installation directory, everything is fine. There is a do_populate_sysroot step and when booting the image all the needed files are present.

**The bbappend recipe:**

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI_append = " \
    file://NetworkManager.conf \
"

# Current path in install directory
PATH_PKG = "${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager"

# New path in install directory
NEW_PATH_PKG = "${D}/data/NetworkManager"  

# New path on target
NEW_PATH_ROOTFS = "/data/NetworkManager"


FILES_${PN}_append = " \
    ${NEW_PATH_ROOTFS} \
"

FILES_${PN}-cloud-setup = " \
    ${NEW_PATH_ROOTFS} \
"


# This variable contains directories that are installed by default
##### Adding this doesn't seem to do anything
SYSROOT_DIRS += "/data/NetworkManager"

# The package needs to be moved to a readwrite location.

do_install_append() {

    echo "### NetworkManager bbappend installation START ###"
    echo "\n"
    echo "Current NetworkManager path = ${PATH_PKG}"
    echo "New NetworkManager path = ${NEW_PATH_ROOTFS}"

    # Remove existing directories:
    rm -rfv ${PATH_PKG}/conf.d
    rm -rfv ${PATH_PKG}/dispatcher.d
    rm -rfv ${PATH_PKG}/VPN
    rm -rfv ${PATH_PKG}/system-connections
    
    # Create end-point folders
    install -dv ${NEW_PATH_PKG}/conf.d
    install -dv ${NEW_PATH_PKG}/dispatcher.d/pre-down.d
    install -dv ${NEW_PATH_PKG}/dispatcher.d/pre-up.d
    install -dv ${NEW_PATH_PKG}/dispatcher.d/no-wait.d
    install -dv ${NEW_PATH_PKG}/VPN
    install -dv ${NEW_PATH_PKG}/system-connections
    
    # Create symlink for common directory
    ln -sv ${NEW_PATH_ROOTFS}/conf.d                     ${PATH_PKG}/conf.d                      
    ln -sv ${NEW_PATH_ROOTFS}/dispatcher.d               ${PATH_PKG}/dispatcher.d              
    ln -sv ${NEW_PATH_ROOTFS}/VPN                        ${PATH_PKG}/VPN                         
    ln -sv ${NEW_PATH_ROOTFS}/system-connections         ${PATH_PKG}/system-connections                        

    # Add custom configuration for Network Manager
    install -v -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/NetworkManager.conf ${NEW_PATH_PKG}
    ln -sv ${NEW_PATH_ROOTFS}/NetworkManager.conf ${PATH_PKG}/NetworkManager.conf

    echo "### NetworkManager bbappend installation FINISH ###"
    echo "\n"
}
```

I thought SYSROOT_DIRS was the issue but unfortunately not in this case. Maybe someone has an idea what else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

So I wasn't able to determine the exact cause but found an alternative - "volatile_binds" image feature.

It allows to sort-of overlay a writeable location (I chose tmpfs), on top of a read-only directory.

The best thing is that it is package-agnostic.